# Castle Windsor passing constructor parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ioc-container

I have an IAddress class with a few properties.  I then have a concrete type that implements this interface.  This concrete type has a couple of different constructors I could use.  How can I pass parameter values to one of these constructors at run-time?  I cannot use the config file as I will be reusing this concrete type multiple times and each time the parameter values will be different.

```cs
IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter());
IAddress address = container.Resolve<IAddress>();


public interface IAddress
{
    string Address1 { get; set; }
    string Address2 { get; set; }
    string City { get; set; }
    string State { get; set; }
    string ZipCode { get; set; }
}


class TestAddress : IAddress
{

    private string _address1;
    private string _address2;
    private string _city;
    private string _countyName;
    private string _state;
    private string _zipCode;

    public string Address1
    {
        get { return _address1; }
        set { _address1 = value; }
    }

    public string Address2
    {
        get { return _address2; }
        set { _address2 = value; }
    }

    public string City
    {
        get { return _city; }
        set { _city = value; }
    }

    public string State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }

    public string ZipCode
    {
        get { return _zipCode; }
        set { _zipCode = value; }
    }

    public string CountyName
    {
        get { return _countyName; }
        set { _countyName = value; }
    }


    public MelissaAddress(string address1, string address2, string city, string state, string zipcode)
    {
        Address1 = address1;
        Address2 = address2;
        City = city;
        State = state;
        ZipCode = zipcode;
    }

    public MelissaAddress(string address1, string address2, string zipcode) : this(address1, address2, null, null, zipcode)
    { }

    public MelissaAddress(string address1, string address2, string city, string state) : this(address1, address2, city, state, null)
    { }
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code or just some sample? It looks like you're using the container as a replacement for new().

Comment: do you want to specify parameters at registration-time or resolution-time?

Comment: I'd like to specify the parameters at resolution time.  If I need 2 address classes each with a different address then I'd like to pass the values to each class in the constructor.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use `Resolve(object argumentsAsAnonymousType)` or `Resolve(IDictionary arguments)`. Windsor will select the best matching constructor.

For example this will select your second constructor:

```cs
container.Resolve<IAddress>(
    new {address1 = "myaddress1", address2 = "myaddress2", zipcode = "myzipcode"}
)
```

Comment: You might also consider wrapping this invocation in a factory, or if you get addresses from elsewhere - using ISubDependencyResolver to provide them to the container, instead of passing them from the call site (if this is an option)

Comment: Hmm, interesting.  What if you're using the MS CommonServiceLocator rather than directly calling into Castle Windsor, though?  Some sort of facility?

Comment: Is it possible to just pass some arguments and have other arguments in the same constructor, resolved by castle windsor?

Comment: @SideFX: no, but what you're probably asking about is done at registration time, not at resolution-time. Post a new question with all relevant details.

Comment: SideFX, Mauricio: Actually what SideFX asks is perfectly possible as I'm doing it right now.  Whatever you don't provide castle will try to resolve for you.

Comment: And if in the caller I don't have any reference to the container? (I'm in a DLL which is loaded somehow by windsor). Where the the operation of Resolve is called I still don't have the parameters to pass to the method..