# How pass parameter to ITypedFactory method to more than the immediate class being created

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have the following class hierarchy:

```
public class FirstProvider : IFirstProvider
{        
    public FirstProvider (string data, ISecondProvider provider)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public class SecondProvider : ISecondProvider
{
    public SecondProvider (string data)
    {
        ...
    }
}

public interface IProviderFactory
{
    T Create<T>(string data) where T : IProvider;
}
```

IFirstProvider and ISecondProvider both implement IProvider and are registered properly on the container.  What I am trying to do is to obtain an instance of FirstProvider from my IProviderFactory like so:

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    var provider = _providerFactory.Create<IFirstProvider>("my data");
}
```

At this point I receive the following exception:

"Missing dependency.

Component SecondProvider has a dependency on string, which could not be resolved.

Make sure the dependency is correctly registered in the container as a service, or provided as inline argument."

It would appear that Windsor does not pass the parameters of the ITypedFactory through the chain of dependencies it has to resolve to create the instance of the class.  Is there another way I can support this design or should I reconsider my design?

Comment: Also, I know I can pass my factory to FirstProvider but I don't like this option.

Comment: Do you want the same string parameter to be passed to the second provider constructor as well?

Comment: Yes, I want the same string to be passed to the second provider constructor as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that components are not registered correctly for your needs.
Could you provide a block of registration code?

I think you should try ["a delegate as component factory"](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx#Using_a_delegate_as_component_factory_6) to solve your issue.
There are several overloads that might help you.

Something like this:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ISecondProvider>().
    .UsingFactoryMethod(container =>
    {
        /* your code */
    }));
container.Register(Component.For<IFirstProvider>().
    .UsingFactoryMethod(container =>
    {
        var prvoider = container.Resolve<ISecondProvider>();
        /* your code */
    }));
```

Also it is possible [to pass arguments when you resolve a type](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Passing-Arguments.ashx?HL=resolve#Passing_arguments_7).
There is an answered question "[Castle Windsor passing constructor parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784253/castle-windsor-passing-constructor-parameters)".

Comment: I am just hoping to use (or extend) the typed factory facility instead of factories for specific providers.  In the second link you posted there is an info box titled "Inline dependencies don't get propagated" which says that my scenario is not supported out of the box.  I must have missed this when reading the docs.